# adding element with array_push() with looping to create json data

Tags: javascript, php, json, highcharts

I want to create JSON data which looks like this

> [{"name":"AS","data":["150","250","300"]},{"name":"JS","data":["175","180","210"]},{"name":"MS","data":["100","75","200"]}]

and here is the script that I have created

```
$c = mysql_query("SELECT distinct nama FROM tcoba ORDER BY nama ASC"); 
while($ca = mysql_fetch_array($c))
{
    $cb[] = $ca['nama'];
}
$cc = array();
$cc = count($cb);
if(count($cb) > 1)
{
    for($i=0;$i<$cc;$i++)
    {
        $b = mysql_query("SELECT distinct nama, jumlah FROM tcoba WHERE nama = '$cb[$i]'");
        $rows = array();
        while($ba = mysql_fetch_array($b)) 
        {
            $rows['name'] = $ba[0];
            $rows['data'][] = $ba['jumlah'];
        }
        $result = array(); 
        array_push($result,$rows);
        print json_encode($result);
    }
}
```

**and the result from my script is**

> [{"name":"AS","data":["150","250","300"]}][{"name":"JS","data":["175","180","210"]}][{"name":"MS","data":["100","75","200"]}]

still not match with what I want to show...

EDIT : WORK

```
$result = array(); 
for($i=0;$i<$cc;$i++)
{
    $b = mysql_query("SELECT distinct nama, jumlah FROM tcoba WHERE nama = '$cb[$i]'");
    $rows = array();
    while($ba = mysql_fetch_array($b)) 
    {
        $rows['name'] = $ba[0];
        $rows['data'][] = $ba['jumlah'];
    }

    array_push($result,$rows);

}print json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the print after the for loop, and don't reinitialize `$result` to an empty array inside of the loop.

Also...

```
$cc = array();
$cc = count($cb);
```

One of those lines is redundant (probably the first).

Comment: how to not reinitialize $result inside the loop?
have an example?

Comment: The line: `$result = array();` Try moving that above the for loop.  Right now you're emptying it out every single time it runs through that loop.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things wrong with your code:

- you're re-inializing the array on each iteration
- you're printing the JSON string on each iteration

What you're seeing as the output is three JSON strings combined. As there are no line breaks in your code, it'll appear as one big JSON string.

Your code should look like:

```
$result = array(); // initialize the array
while($ba = mysql_fetch_array($b)) 
{
    $rows['name'] = $ba[0];
    $rows['data'][] = $ba['jumlah'];
    array_push($result,$rows);
}
print json_encode($result);
```

Comment: solved dude

$result = array();
for($i=0;$i<$cc;$i++)
    { 
while($ba = mysql_fetch_array($b)) 
{
    $rows['name'] = $ba[0];
    $rows['data'][] = $ba['jumlah'];
    array_push($result,$rows);
}
)
print json_encode($result);

using that script

Comment: sorry, i'm noob here... :) but already give a check to watcher

Answer (score 0):

Move `$result = array();` to occur before the loop, perhaps even before the if-block. You can probably handle the code from there.

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts use number data, but your data is a array of strings. So you need to parse it by parseFloat() or use json_encode() with JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK which allows to return correct JSON values.